# Regular Expression - Avoid a string in expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to create a regex that should match following cases.
if exact match of words `'first, second, third'` then match should fail - but if there are any characters around it, then the string should be matched.

Also I need to avoid certain set of characters in the string. [()!=<>", ] - if these characters are part of string then match result should fail.

I looked at few examples & negative look ahead but did not get the right regex yet.

```
^(?!first$|second$|third$|fou rth$)[^()!=<>", ]+
```

desired output:

```
first - fail
second - fail
1first - pass
first1 - pass
1first1 - pass
fou rth - fail - it has space in between word and is from ignore list
newTest - pass
new(test - fail - since ( is not allowed character
space word - fail - since space is non allowed character
```

The regex needs to support case insensitive words

Any help appreciated. I am using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`^(?!.*[()!=<>", ])(?!(?:first|second|third)$).+$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ngLGH6/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?!.*[()!=<>", ])` - negative lookahead to validate that the test string does not contain any of these characters - `(`, `)`, `!`, `=`, `<`, `>`, `,`,
- `(?!(?:first|second|third)$)` - At this moment we are at the beginning of the test string. This position should not be immediately followed by (`first` or `second` or `third`) and then by the end of the string(`$`)
- `.+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character but not a newline character
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Comment: To the person who has down-voted, would you mind explaining your reason?