# Represent a Regex in Peg.js way

Tags: javascript, regex, peg

I am using Peg.js grammar validation. I have following regex, but I am not able to represent same in the peg syntax.

How can I represent following regex in the PEG way?

```
^(?!.*[()!=<>", ])(?!(?:first|second|third)$).+$
```

If I use following I get **Syntax error**-

> someRule = ^(?!.*[()!=<>", ])(?!(?:first|second|third)$).+$

**message**: "**Expected** "!", "$", "&", "(", ".", character class,…identifier, literal, or whitespace but "^" found."

The scenarios that I am looking for are mentioned as:
[Scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236712/regular-expression-avoid-a-string-in-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Complex regular expressions can't be put into PEG with no preparation.  (I am assuming that you want to create a grammar for the language recognized by your regex, not that you are looking to recognize your regex literal.)

For example, the `^` and `$` characters have no special meaning in PEG.  Similarly, the `?!` and `?:` constructions have no special meaning.

While PEG has some constructions that are regex-like, it is really far more general, and has a completely different syntax.